# How to include adjustable parameter in fsolve?

Tags: python, parameters, system, equation, non-linear

I'm getting familiar with *fsolve* in Python and I am having trouble including adjustable parameters in my system of nonlinear equations. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670094/solving-equations-with-parameters-python-fsolve) seems to answer my question but I still get errors. Below is my code:

```
 import scipy.optimize as so

 def test(x,y,z):
    
     eq1 = x**2+y**2-z
     eq2 = 2*x+1
    
     return [eq1,eq2]

     z = 1                                         # Ajustable parameter
     sol = so.fsolve(test , [-1,2] ,args=(z))      # Solution Array
     print(sol)                                    # Display Solution
```

The output gives

```
    TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'
```

When *z* is clearly defined as an argument. How do I include this adjustable parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So before posting here I should have spent a little bit more time playing with it. Here is what I found

```
import scipy.optimize as so
import numpy as np

def test(variables,z): #Define function of variables and adjustable arg
    
    x,y = variables     #Declare variables
    
    eq1 = x**2+y**2-1-z #Equation to solve #1
    eq2 = 2*x+1         #Equation to solve #2
    
    return [eq1,eq2]    #Return equation array

z = 1                                       #Ajustable parameter
initial = [1,2]                             #Initial condition list                          
sol = so.fsolve(test , initial, args = (z)) #Call fsolve
print(np.array(sol))                        #Display sol
```

With an output

```
[-0.5         1.32287566]
```

I'm not the best at analyzing code, but I *think* my issue was that I had mixed up my variables and arguments in `test(x,y,z)` such that it didn't know what I was trying to apply the initial guess to.

Anyway, I hope this helped someone.

edit: While I'm here, the test function is a circle of adjustable radius and a line that intersects it at two points.

[image: Red: x^2+y^2-2, Blue: 2x+1]

If you wanted to find the positive and negative solutions, you'd need to pass your initial guess in as an array (someone asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054758/python-finding-multiple-roots-of-nonlinear-equation)). Here is the updated version

```
z = 1
initial = [[-2,-1],[2,1]]
sol = []                            
for i in range(len(initial)): 
   sol.append(so.fsolve(test , initial[i], args = (z))) 
print(np.array(sol))
```

The output is

```
[[-0.5        -1.32287566]
 [-0.5         1.32287566]]
```